# SQL Query: How to Select across rows and columns

Tags: html, sql, sql-server-2008

I'm certain that this is a simple WHERE clause. I'm just not sure how to write it.

Let's say I have the following data where a,b,c(numbers) and d(varchar):

[image]

What I'd like to do is select rows that have the following conditions:

- Column b must be the same as at least one other row.
- Column c must
  have at least one row with a value and one without or one with 0 as a
  value.

I'd like to pull in col a and d. But only if b and c meet those conditions.

For example the green data is something I'd like to select, and the red is obviously data I don't care about. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm confused by the requirements for c. Why not bring in the two red rows? It looks like they meet the conditions for b and then "have at least one row with a value" in column c

Comment: @kbball The keyword in that requirement is AND. Sure they both have a value, but one of them is not 0 or null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

SAMPLE DATA:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TABLE') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TABLE

CREATE TABLE #TABLE (A int, B int , C int) 

INSERT INTO  #TABLE ( A, B  , C )  
VALUES
(0,1,0),
(1,1,253),
(2,4,800),
(3,5,460),
(4,6,300),
(5,7,350),
(6,7,450)
```

QUERY:

```
;WITH CTE --<-- this is a common table expression, it is essentially the same as having temp tables but it is in memory. Just google CTE tSQL and you will find out more about it.
    AS (SELECT *
            , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY B ORDER BY A) --this assigns a row number to the rows that are partitioned by the values in B. 
        FROM   #TABLE)
    SELECT A
        , B
        , C
    FROM   CTE
    WHERE  B IN
             (SELECT B --<-- here filter to only return the rows that have an rn (row number) greater than 1 meaning there are more than one row for the given value in B
              FROM   CTE
              WHERE  rn > 1) AND B IN (SELECT B --<-- here we filter further to ensure at least 1 record has the value 0.
              FROM   CTE
              WHERE C = 0 AND B IN (SELECT B --<--this is to ensure that at least there is one value that is not 0 to handle the bug pointed out by Jay.
          FROM   CTE
          WHERE C <> 0));
```

RESULTS:

[image]

More about [CTE's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms175972.aspx)

More about [ROW_NUMBER()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Comment: This appears to work but before I implement it, could you explain what it does?

Comment: sure I will edit the answer. Please see the comments in the answer. Let me know if you need any further explanation.

Comment: If Row #2 also had a value of 0 for column C.  Wouldn't this still pick up both rows and wouldn't that be against the OP question?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Jay that is correct! lem see how I would fix that bug

Comment: Ok that bug is now fixed

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the `b` values, using aggregation and `having`:

```
select b
from t
group by b
having count(*) > 1 and
       max(c) > 0 and
       min(coalesce(c, 0)) = 0;
```

This assumes that `c` is always positive.  Similar logic can be formulated if `c` can be negative.

If you want the original rows, you can join these results back to the table, or use `in`.

Comment: I think, column c may contains 0 or no zeros. So seems like OR could be used.

Comment: @AT-2016 not no zeros -- no value.  That is why Gordon used coalesce.

Comment: @AT-2016 . . . That doesn't make a difference.  This works with both 0 and NULL, as Hogan points out.  And, it appears to be much simpler than other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JOINS as well to produce the desired result as:

```
SELECT [tab].*
FROM
(
    SELECT tab1.B
    FROM #TABLE tab1
    GROUP BY tab1.B
    HAVING COUNT(tab1.A) > 1
) Tab1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT tab2.B
    FROM #TABLE tab2
    WHERE tab2.C IS NOT NULL
          AND (tab2.C IS NULL
               OR tab2.C = 0)
    GROUP BY tab2.B
) Tab2 ON Tab1.B = Tab2.B
INNER JOIN #TABLE [tab] ON tab.B = Tab2.B;
```